# Does bagearth in caret respect the trim option?

Tags: r, memory, r-caret, training-data

In this question ([r caret estimate parameters on a subset fit to full data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590157/r-caret-estimate-parameters-on-a-subset-fit-to-full-data)) I was told how to be flexible in the amount of data used in training, testing and final model fitting within the r caret package. I am using 10k data for training, 5k for testing and 20k for a final model fit with 5 samples (not 10 as used in the above answer). Twelve datasets are fitted using (1) generalised linear model, (2) gradient boost, (3) support vector machine, (4) cubists and (5) bag earth (MARS). I have used the trim option of fit control to limit the amount of information saved in the results. Looking at the size of the 12-element lists to hold the results I get:

```
 > print(object.size(fit000.list), units = "MB")
521.4 Mb
> print(object.size(fit002.list), units = "MB")
742.8 Mb
> print(object.size(fit003.list), units = "MB")
584.2 Mb
> print(object.size(fit004.list), units = "MB")
576.8 Mb
> print(object.size(fit005.list), units = "MB")
8895.8 Mb
```

You will see that the last list, for bag earth is much larger than the others (x 10). Looking at the structure of one of these twelve fits I see that there is a finalModel$fit list of 50 Resamples, which are large and there are 50 of them:

```
> print(object.size(fit005.list[[1]]$finalModel), units = "MB")
699.2 Mb
> print(object.size(fit005.list[[1]]$finalModel$fit), units = "MB")
679.2 Mb
> print(object.size(fit005.list[[1]]$finalModel$fit$Resample01), units = "MB")
13.6 Mb
```

Does anyone know if bag earth is naturally this large?

Is it not respecting the trim option in fit control?

Does anyone know if I can control the number of ResampleXX?

If not, can I 'manually' nullify them with little or no consequence?

Thanks.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/76) might be of  interested although a bit old.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably use the B option to limit bagging to 10 samples. In Kuhn's Applied Predictive Modeling book, for this data beyond 10 bagging did not appear to improve things. keepX=FALSE appears to be a useful option too.